# A table element becomes nil, after it is set to an integer

Tags: lua, love2d

I am trying to make a Basic Entity Component System and I’ve got this error on my lua scripts (working with Love2D).
I don´t know where the problem is:

Error: systems.lua:11: bad argument #2 to 'rectangle' (number expected, got nil)

> main.lua

```
local system = require "systems"

function love.load()
    system.newPlayer()
end

function love.draw()
    system.drawPlayer()
end
```

> systems.lua

```
local S = {}

local entities = require "entities"
local components = require "components"

function S.newPlayer()
    entities.player()
end

function S.drawPlayer()
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",components.getX(1),components.getY(1), 10, 10)
end

return S
```

> entities.lua

```
local components = require "components"

local E = {}

function E.player()
    components.setX(1,20)
    components.setY(1,20)
end

return E
```

> components.lua

```
local C = {}

local x = {}
function C.setX(key, value)
    x.key = value
end
function C.getX(index)
    return x.index
end

local y = {}
function C.setY(key, value)
    y.key = value
end
function C.getY(index)
    return y.index
end

return C
```

I trace the error to entities.lua when calling components.setX(1,20), because after that, printing the key´s value is nil, eventhough the function set it to 20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
x.key = value
```

the key is the string value `"key"`.

If you want the key to be the value of the variable `key`, do

```
x[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use numbers as keys for tables. You can do two things (choose one):

- In set and get functions put the key inside brackets:

```lua
function C.getX(index)
  return x[index]
end

function C.setX(key, value)
  x[key] = value
end

-- same for y
```

- Or specify the key between quotes when using your functions

```lua
components.getX("1")
components.setX("1",20)
```

Comment: Actually, you can use any value as a key except `nil` or NaN: boolean, number, string, function, table, userdata.

Comment: @cyclaminist what i meant with "you can't use numbers" is that you can't do print(table.2), and same with booleans, you can't do print(table.true). You have to use them between quotes and brackets, but they are not numbers or booleans anymore but strings.

Comment: Okay, I see. It was confusingly phrased.